# Basic classNames not working in new React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Just created a new react app using 'npx create-react-app my-app' (so the webpack and all modules were configured for me) and none of my classNames are being implemented. In case it was something I was doing wrong, I tried copying and pasting basic ones like the navbar examples from react-bootstrap.

It's displaying the text for the navbar but none of the styling. Anyone run into this or have an idea of what could be the problem?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
       <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
      </Navbar>
      <>
       <div className="d-flex flex-row">
         <div className="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
         <div className="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
         <div className="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
       </div>
      </>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where are you including the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed react-bootstrap? If not just enter

```
npm install react-bootstrap
```

It will then install all the necessary files.

Comment: Or npx install whatever you prefer

Comment: Or yarn add or whatever you prefer

Answer (score 0):

Some stylesheets are required to use these components. So you should define it as below.

```
{/* The following line can be included in your src/index.js or App.js file*/}

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: Do we have to include `css` even if we installed the package?

Comment: Yes, you should. There is a section in [doc](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets) actually